# Enumerable.Repeat has some memory issues?

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I initialized an Array as

```
Double[][] myarr = Enumerable.Repeat(new double[12], 13).ToArray();
```

Then in a loop i am incrementing values like

```
myarr[0][0]++;
```

This causes all values like myarr[1][0], myarr[2][0], myarr[3][0] ..... myarr[12][0] to increment by one.

This problem is not occurring when using a for loop (0-12) i am initializing like

```
myarr[i] = new double[12];
```

Why is this so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Other answers have explained the problem. The solution is to create a new array on each iteration, e.g.

```
double[][] myarr = Enumerable.Range(0, 13)
                             .Select(ignored => new double[12])
                             .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

With `new double[12]` you are creating reference to array of doubles, and then you repeate the **reference** 12 times, so myarr[0..n] will have reference to one memory region.

You can use the folowing method to resolve thw issue

```
static T[][] CreateArray<T>(int rows, int cols)
{
    T[][] array = new T[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        array[i] = new T[cols];

    return array;
}
```

Or with custom Repeat method which calls action every step:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> RepeatAction<TResult>(Action<TResult> elementAction, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return elementAction();
    }
    yield break;
}
usage
RepeatAction(()=>new double[12], 12);
```

Answer (score 2):

It's because `new double[12]` creates a single array object in memory - Enumerable.Repeat is simply providing you with multiple references to that array.

Comment: What is the use of such facility(multiple references to that array)? It will give wrong values to array.

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behavior - array is a referebce type. You are creating a jagged array i.e. array of arrays. All elements of your outer array references the same inside array i.e the first argument of `Repeat` call, so changes in the inside array will be reflected at on indices (because all indices refer to the same array).

Comment: What is the use of such facility(multiple references to that array)? It will give wrong values to array.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays are references. In the `Repeat` call you create one array and assign its reference 12 times. In your loop however you create 12 distinct arrays.

Answer (score 1):

`Repeat()` basically just capture and yields the same element multiple times, so you got multiple references to the same object instance in the memory.

This is how `Repeat()` is implemented:

```
private static IEnumerable<TResult> RepeatIterator<TResult>(TResult element, int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        yield return element;
    }
    yield break;
}
```