# Array Initialization ways

Tags: c#, linq

I know that we can initialise an array in one of two ways:

1. Loop (No Memory reflection issues)
2. `Enumerable.Repeat` (Probably causes memory issues? Link: [Enumerable.Repeat has some memory issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10071032/enumerable-repeat-has-some-memory-issues))

I have two questions:

1. Can we initialise an array using `Array.ForEach` in this manner?

   ```
   double[][] myarr = new double[13][];

   Array.ForEach(myarr, *enter_code_here*);
   ```

   I tried replacing `enter_code_here` with:

   ```
   s => s = new double[2];
   ```

   but it does not initialise `myarr`.
2. What are the other array initialisation methods without any memory issues?

Comment: `Enumerable.Repeat` does not have issues. Programmers who do not understand how it works and misuse it have.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `Enumerable.Repeat` just fine to initialize any array. The only thing you need to be careful of is that if the array element is of a reference type there are two ways to go about it:

```
// #1: THIS ARRAY CONTAINS 10 REFERENCES TO THE SAME OBJECT
var myarr = Enumerable.Repeat(new object(), 10).ToArray();

// #2: THIS ARRAY CONTAINS REFERENCES TO 10 DIFFERENT OBJECTS
var myarr = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(i => new object()).ToArray();

// #3: SAME RESULT AS #2 BUT WITH Enumerable.Repeat
var myarr = Enumerable.Repeat(0, 10).Select(i => new object()).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

A1: No, you can't. Foreach just executes method with element as parameter but don't modify elements.

A2:
You can use the folowing method to resolve the issue

```
static T[][] CreateArray<T>(int rows, int cols)
{
    T[][] array = new T[rows][];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
        array[i] = new T[cols];

    return array;
}
```

Comment: +1 for "No, you can't. Foreach just executes method with element as parameter but don't modify elements."

Answer (score 0):

This is how I created a 256 row x 2 column array and initialized all values to -1.

`int[][] myArr = Enumerable.Range(0, 256).Select(i => new int[2] {-1, -1}).ToArray();`